# Lifting the Cartier operator to the p-adics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

The Cartier operator is defined for smooth varieties over finite fields. If $C$ is an algebraic curver over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Let $C_p$ the reduction of $C$ to positive characteristic. My question is if we can lift the cartier operator from $C_p$ to $C$. If it is posible, in modular curves, this lift has relation with the Hecke operator?.